# Qt Creator doesn't find my Android device

Tags: android, qt, windows-7, adb, qt-creator

The steps I've taken so far are:

1. Downloaded qt-opensource-windows-x86-android-5.3.0-RC.exe from http://download.qt-project.org/development_releases/qt/5.3/5.3.0-rc/ and installed it.
2. Downloaded the Android SDK, etc., according to Creator's Android Configurations dialog:[image: qt-creator-android-settings]
3. Ran my application. A dialog came up saying `Device not found`, and suggesting that I run `adb devices` to see if the device is indeed available. I ran that, but no devices were connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading [this blog post](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2014/03/26/qt-weekly-3-qt-for-android-tips-and-tricks/), I found out that it was necessary to install Google's USB Driver that was downloaded when I ran the SDK Manager. The instructions for doing so are [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html).