# trouble setting android dev environment Qt

Tags: android, c++, qt, qml, android-sdk-tools

After reading several blogs and official documentation i learned how to setup qt for android, but unfortunately i ran into a bizarre problem and am not able to go over it.

1.android configuration 
[image: android configuration]

2. my qt versions snapshots 
   [image: qt version snapshots]
3. kits selection
   [image: kit setting]
4. finally my build and run kit selection
   [image: project setting]

As you could see am trying to test my application for armeabi-v7a ARCH and i have selected all the right kits. At least i hope!! But am not sure **When i run my application am getting the device window showing my AVD in incompatible devices list**

5. device selection window
   [image: device selection window]

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22238649/qt5-for-android-incompatible-abi

Comment: May be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23571098/qt-creator-doesnt-find-my-android-device

Comment: yes i figured how to solve my problem. Thanks